# An image viewer like Picasa Picture Viewer

Tags: windows, image-viewer

I used to use Picasa's Picture Viewer (which is bundled with the main Picasa app, but works separately from it). It worked great.

Now I moved to a new Windows 10 laptop and when I attempted to download Picasa for the Picasa Picture Viewer, I saw it was discontinued. I don't want to download it from third party sites, since it's unsupported now.

My requirements for an image viewer, most of which Windows 10's "Photos" app doesn't fulfill, and Picasa Picture Viewer did:

- Show image instantly
- Easy way to show the image at 1:1 scale, i.e. unscaled
- Easy way to fit the image to the window
- Easy way to increase and decrease zoom level
- Preferably a simple UI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use [Honeyview](https://www.bandisoft.com/honeyview/) for a while now on Windows, it's one of the closest to Picasa Picture Viewer I know. The UI is easy to customize and has lot of features.

Other alternative I use include *(both available for Linux, Mac and Windows)*:

- [Nomacs](http://nomacs.org/screenshots/)
- [PhotoQt](http://photoqt.org/feat/)

[image]

Other

Comment: Thanks. PhotoQt is nice, quite close to Picasa, but unfortunately it takes about 4 seconds to start. I settled on Honeyview. Its main shortcoming is that it doesn't have a "filmstrip" at the bottom (like PhotoQt and Picasa). But  that's not a big problem.

Comment: Yeah, It's kinda heavy. Nomacs have the "filmstrip" you can place everywhere. And you can use the F10 key to have a frameless  display like in Picasa: https://i.imgur.com/pveh1Sm.jpg , and it's quite fast too.

Comment: I tried PhotoQT on Ubuntu and it mostly replicated Picasa. From transparent background to the rounded close button. It is also responsive. It's either from 2 years of development or just works better on Linux. The only thing I needed to change is the scroll shortcuts: from Ctrl+WheelUp for "zooming out" to just WheelDown for "zooming out". Seems this way is more natural to me.

Comment: Just one minor thing of PhotoQT for improvement might be to allow zooming at the position of the mouse cursor, because it currently does not function that way.

Answer (score 2):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) sounds like a winner - it's portable and fast.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I like that it's a fast and mature app (I remember it from maybe 1997 when I got my first PC). But it's kinda ugly, I can't drag the image around, pressing left and right shows also txt files and such, I can't zoom with just the mouse wheel, doesn't give an indication where I am in the image list... it probably fits the question as stated, though, so thanks :)